# Pinterest Pin It Hover Widget doesn't work on my website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pinterest

I'm trying to add the Pinterest Pin It Hover Button on my website. However, despite following the docs closely, I haven't been able to do so. Here's what I've done so far...

I've added the following code in the footer for my website.
`<script data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-save="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>`

I've tested and verified that `pinit.js` loads correctly, and further loads `pinit.main.js` as well. But I can see that the `mouseover` event doesn't seem to be attached to the `<body>` tag. I don't see any relevant console errors either.

Some more details...
My website is built on Wordpress with a custom theme. I'm not using any plugins to insert the call to `pinit.js`, thats custom code.

Example URLs:
http://www.curejoy.com/content/sweet-potatoes-good-for-diabetes/
http://www.curejoy.com/content/running-for-depression/

Looking forward to your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure the script is at the end of your body tag.

Comment: @ZackArgyle is that why it isn't working though? I have verified on jsfiddle that the pinit button works fine as long as the script is placed anywhere in the page. Ex: this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q13qg8h1/ - has the script placed in its <head> tag; and still works fine. As of now, its a little difficult to ensure that the script gets placed at the end of the body tag (because of tags being dynamically inserted), hence am not able to immediately carry out your suggestion.